# textAlign: TextAlign.center, flutter not working

Tags: flutter, dart, text-alignment

I'm a student who is new to learning flutter. I won't align my text and buttons to the center of the screen. I use this code to align the center. also, I used separate widgets to create them as shown in the code.

> textAlign: TextAlign.center,

it doesn't work for me. also, the text box I created is not displaying at all. how to fix these errors on my app.

[image]

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
    
    class babyNameScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      const babyNameScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _babyNameScreenState createState() => _babyNameScreenState();
    }
    
    class _babyNameScreenState extends State<babyNameScreen> {
      @override
      @override
      void initState() {
        // TODO: implement initState
        super.initState();
        SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: []);
      }
    
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            leading: IconButton(
              icon: new Icon(
                Icons.arrow_back_rounded,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                // Navigator.push(
                //   context,
                //   MaterialPageRoute(
                //       builder: (context) =>  WelcomeScreen()));
              },
            ),
          ),
    
          body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
    
            child: ListView(
              children: [
                StepText(),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 25,
                ),
                NameText(),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 25,
                ),
                EnterNameText(), 
                // SizedBox(
                //   height: 25,
                // ),
    
                TextBox(),           //text field
                ContinueButton(),  //elevated button
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    
    Widget StepText() => Container(
          child: Row(children: [
            Text(
              'STEP 2/5',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 12,
                color: Colors.deepPurple,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
              ),
            ),
          ]),
        );
    
    Widget NameText() => Container(
          child: Row(children: [
            Text(
              'What is her name?',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 25,
                color: Colors.black,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
    
              ),
            ),
          ]),
        );
    
    
    Widget EnterNameText() => Container(
      child: Row(children: [
        Text(
          'Enter name of your new profile.',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 15,
            color: Colors.grey,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
    
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    );

    //text field

    Widget TextBox()=> Container(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              hintText: 'Enter a search term',
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    
    );
    
//elevated button
    Widget ContinueButton()=> Container (
      child: Row(
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              //playSound(soundNumber);
            },
             child: Text('Continue'),
            style: ButtonStyle(
              backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.deepPurple),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this way to achieve the layout you want

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
    
    class babyNameScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      const babyNameScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _babyNameScreenState createState() => _babyNameScreenState();
    }
    
    class _babyNameScreenState extends State<babyNameScreen> {
      @override
      @override
      void initState() {
        // TODO: implement initState
        super.initState();
        SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: []);
      }
    
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            leading: IconButton(
              icon: new Icon(
                Icons.arrow_back_rounded,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                // Navigator.push(
                //   context,
                //   MaterialPageRoute(
                //       builder: (context) =>  WelcomeScreen()));
              },
            ),
          ),
    
          body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
    
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                StepText(),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 25,
                ),
                NameText(),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 25,
                ),
                EnterNameText(), 
                // SizedBox(
                //   height: 25,
                // ),
    
                TextBox(),           //text field
                ContinueButton(),  //elevated button
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    
    Widget StepText() => Container(
          child: Text(
            'STEP 2/5',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 12,
              color: Colors.deepPurple,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
            ),
          ),
        );
    
    Widget NameText() => Container(
          child: Text(
            'What is her name?',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 25,
              color: Colors.black,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
    
            ),
          ),
        );
    
    
    Widget EnterNameText() => Container(
      child: Text(
        'Enter name of your new profile.',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 15,
          color: Colors.grey,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
    
        ),
      ),
    );

    //text field

    Widget TextBox()=> Container(
      child: TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          hintText: 'Enter a search term',
        ),
      ),
    
    );
    
//elevated button
    Widget ContinueButton()=> Container (
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          //playSound(soundNumber);
        },
         child: Text('Continue'),
        style: ButtonStyle(
          backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.deepPurple),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: thank you also is there a way to remove the app bar and just keep the arrow icon only.

Comment: You can use Stack or go inside appbar and set background color transparent then, give it elevation 0.

Comment: you can set the background color of app bar to transparent and set color of back button with iconthemedata

Answer (score 0):

Use,  `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center` in `Row`.

Like this,

```
    Widget StepText() => Container(
        child: Row(
             mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, // Add this line...
              children: [
                Text(
                  'STEP 2/5',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 12,
                    color: Colors.deepPurple,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
            );
```

For more info : https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout

For remove shadow of AppBar use elevation,

```
appBar: AppBar(
       backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
       elevation: 0.0,)
```

For more info : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Material/elevation.html

Comment: thank you it worked. can you also tell me what's wrong with the textbox I have created? it's not working at all

Comment: Because you have added Text under Row. So Row is parent Widget and by default Row start with left side. If you remove Row and Direct use Text Widget then it works.